# Can't copy eclipse unicode art console output

Tags: java, file, unicode, console

It's a program that gets an image. then turn it black and white. and then into unicode art.
The keyboard does support the unicode characters since I was printing it earlier. I stopped working after I resized the source image.
I'm using 8dots Braille. like this ⣿,⢆

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter; 
public class BlackAndWhitePrint {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String homeAdress = "C:\\Users\\taban\\eclipse-workspace\\BlackAndWhitePrint\\";
      String FileName = "C:\\Users\\taban\\eclipse-workspace\\BlackAndWhitePrint\\shakh.jpg";
            File input = new File(FileName);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

            BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
                    image.getWidth(),
                    image.getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

            Graphics2D graphic = result.createGraphics();
            graphic.drawImage(image, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
            graphic.dispose();

            File output = new File(homeAdress+"shakhEdit.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(result, "jpg", output);
//the top part turned the image to black and white and makes an ouput image
            
//in the next part I turn image into and 0and1 matrix       
            int width = result.getWidth();
            int height = result.getHeight();
   
            int[][] bitmap = new int[height][width];
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                    int rgb = result.getRGB(j, i);
                    int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                    int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                    int b = (rgb & 0xFF);
                    int gray = (r + g + b) / 3;
                    
                    bitmap[i][j] = (gray == 0) ? 1:0;//0 too shart mishe shiah. mikham shiah bood type konam.
                    
                }
            }
//now that I have the bitmap, I need the get samples and turn them into unicode characters
            char[][] outputChar = new char[height/4][width/2];
            int[][] subpixle= new int[4][2];
            for (int i = 0; i < height-4; i=i+4) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width-4; j=j+2) {
                    subpixle[0][0]=bitmap[i][j];
                    subpixle[0][1]=bitmap[i][j+1];
                    subpixle[1][0]=bitmap[i+1][j];
                    subpixle[1][1]=bitmap[i+1][j+1];
                    subpixle[2][0]=bitmap[i+2][j];
                    subpixle[2][1]=bitmap[i+2][j+1];
                    subpixle[3][0]=bitmap[i+3][j];
                    subpixle[3][1]=bitmap[i+3][j+1];
                    outputChar[i/4][j/2]= TurnTo8DotsBraille(subpixle);
                }
                
            }
//here I print them in the  console, it works fine
            PrintTheChar(outputChar);
//then I print into file, but it doesnt write anything
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(homeAdress+"output.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < outputChar.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < outputChar[i].length; j++) {
                    writer.write(outputChar[i][j]);
                }
                writer.write('\n');
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("FAILD");
        }
  }
  
  
  public static char TurnTo8DotsBraille(int[][] subPixle){
      int out=0;
      if (subPixle[0][0] == 1) out = out + 1;
      if (subPixle[0][1] == 1) out = out + 1000;
      if (subPixle[1][0] == 1) out = out + 10;
      if (subPixle[1][1] == 1) out = out + 10000;
      if (subPixle[2][0] == 1) out = out + 100;
      if (subPixle[2][1] == 1) out = out + 100000;
      if (subPixle[3][0] == 1) out = out + 1000000;
      if (subPixle[3][1] == 1) out = out + 10000000;
      String outString = ""+out;
      int decimal=Integer.parseInt(outString,2);  
      char ch = (char)(decimal+10240);
      return ch;
  }

  public static void PrintTheChar(char[][] input) {
      for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(input[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

here is the console output(it's not the full image since it's my face):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTgpa.png)

I dont know what to do besides resizing the image and forgetting the problem instead of solvong it.
but I really need the file in these aspects:
136*100

Comment: It doesn’t write anything at all?  Does output.txt even exist after the program runs?  If it does exist, what is the size of the file?

Comment: the file is created and is empty and 0 size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I had to flush and close writer.